# Solspace Tags - Import Data

Tags: solspace, tags, solspace-importer

I had to remove and reinstall Solspace tags to fix what I thought was a bug it was causing, and in the process lost all the associated data.

Luckily it was just on a dev server, but I want to add in the data from another mysql database.

Is there a way of importing the data and settings using something like Solspace Importer?

Comment: Is the data, that lives in another MySQL database, in ExpressionEngine tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Solspace Importer](https://solspace.com/docs/importer/) can import Solspace Tags. What you would actually be doing is updating entries, with the update being these tags. You will need something to detect the currently existing entries in your EE installation however, such as an entry title for example. Importer would then be able to detect the existing entry in your system, and apply the tags to the corresponding entry.

Make sure the tags are in one data "field" in your file, eg. a CSV cell, an XML node, etc. Tags will need to be delimited with a character, such as a comma.